# Erlang terminal mute on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: erlang, osx-lion, eshell

I just installed Erlang to my mac using these instructions. http://handyrailstips.com/blog_posts/12-installing-erlang-on-mac-os-x-lion-10-7

Installation worked alright, but when I fired up the Erlang R13B04 Eshell V5.7.5 I immediately started noticing problems - the shell isn't echoing the results of the commands! Actually I'm not even sure if the shell executes the commands at all. Can anyone help me with this?

Here's a sample output:

```
pallo:erlangstuff gro$ erl
Erlang R13B04 (erts-5.7.5) [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [rq:2] [async-threads:0] [hipe][kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.7.5  (abort with ^G)
1> 1 + 1
1> dslakjdlksaj lksajkldsajkdsa
1> "fooo bar baz!"
1>
```

Comment: Never mind. I have to ad a period in the end of the commands to get them executed.

Comment: You can answer the question yourself and mark it as correct after 24 hours, to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to finish the statement with a period:

```
Eshell V5.7.5  (abort with ^G)  
1> 1+1.
2
2>
```